# Fast CGI request in C++ without library

Tags: c++, fastcgi

for a school project I'm doing an HTTP/1.1 compliant server in C++, and i need to communicate with a fast CGI like php-fpm to execute my ".php" files. I have look for documentation and I find that I have to send structures : `FCGI_PARAMS`, `FCGI_STDIN` and `FCGI_DATA` to connection socket. I don't really get it, like what is the form of the request, what do i need to put inside those structure and everything ?

Comment: Aren't the structures the form of the request?

Comment: how do i send a structure thought a socket ?

Comment: with `send` or `write`.

Comment: yeah but i mean you send one field after the other ? can you split a field ?

Comment: What..........?